# Google protobuf 3: deprecated a field, but cannot remove the dependencies?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, proto

I have a proto A that depends on proto B. Then I deprecated the field protoB:

```
import "protoB.proto";

message ProtoA {
  string assignmentStatus = 1;
  protoB proto_b = 2 [deprecated = true];
}
```

I'd think in this case I should be able to remove the `import` statement right? But when I did that, the compiler complains about the dependency not being imported.

What's the deal here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marking something as deprecated just ... marks it as deprecated; for example, in C# the `proto_b` member would be declared but marked as `[Obsolete]`. Since it still exists, it needs to know what to describe it as. The data is still accessible in your application, for example.

If you want to *remove* it: **remove** it:

```proto
message ProtoA {
  string assignmentStatus = 1;
  // field 2 *was* protoB proto_b = 2, now removed
}
```

(leaving a comment is important to avoid people accidentally reusing the field number, which could cause problems with pre-existing data).

Comment: After removing the field you should mark it as `reserved`. This to maintain backwards compatibility while preventing new additions using the same field id. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#reserved).

Comment: thank you! didn't know we can remove a field, i thought the index number is needed to maintain the compatibility.

Comment: @heythere nope; just don't *reuse* it to mean something else, is the main point; you also shouldn't add or remove "required" fields, but proto3 doesn't have the concept of "required"

Comment: @Bart, your comment should really be _the_ answer. Care to convert it?

Comment: It is a bad practice to just remove the field. It is breaking the forward compatibility since tomorrow, the component may use the same filed index for some other information. The best approach here is to mark it as `reserved`.